# How to get the SQL code generate and return code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am executing a Non query SQL.  I will like to know where we go in Visual studio 2013 to see the SQL generated and the error code.

```
    string cmdText = "UPDATE RendezVous SET  
          nomClientEssai=@nomClientEssai,prenomClientEssai=@prenomClientEssai,
          IsAvailable=@IsAvailable WHERE rdvId=@rdvId";

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomClientEssai", Convert.ToString(Session["nom"]));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prenomClientEssai", Convert.ToString(Session["prenom"]));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsAvailable", "False");

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rdvId", cleRdvId);

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    <===  I want to see the sql return code here !!!
    con.Close();
```

This SQL is not updating my table and I want to know why and know how I can verify the SQL statement and also the SQL return code. I don't have any error generated but nothing is getting updated.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are trying to get the final SQL command that is sent to the SQL Server. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: since I don't have an error from the execution, I need to verify which SQL was generated and the return code.  Maybe it will give me a hint of what is not working properly here.  Can you explain me how to check the SQL created and where to find the SQL return code.  If you have any link or example, it will be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The final SQL command that is sent to the SQL Server is `cmdText`. Parameters make it to the SQL server intact.

Comment: Maybe simply `rdvId=@rdvId` matches nothing, so nothing is updated. Can you verify this is correct?

Comment: I checked the rvdId and it is equal to 14 which is the row I wanted to update.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you've managed to to call ExecuteNonQuery with an incorrect command and not get an exception thrown. In SSMS, there's an activity option and you can monitor what sql is being sent. The classic is a "Doh!" where the database you are checking isn't the one you are updating...

Comment: The usual problem when you have a perfectly valid SQL but no update is: you are updating a database but looking at another one. What is your connection string and what is the connection string used in the Server Explorer window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` [returns the number of rows affected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

So update your code as follows and see what is in `numberOfRecordsUpdated` for your `UPDATE` statement.

```
int numberOfRecordsUpdated = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see what's hitting the database, use SQL Profiler

Answer (score 1):

To get information about errors or simple output from the database (anything with severity below or equal to 10 from sql server) you can subscribe to events of the SqlConnection. This is a simple example:

```
con.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler((sender, a) => { Console.WriteLine(a.Message);});
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` does not have a return code.  As mentioned `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the *number* of records affected but it does not tell you *why* that number of records is affected.

I would run it in the debugger to verify the proper value of `cleRdvId` is being used.

Comment: the cleRdvId is set to 14 which correspond to the exact row in the table.  The numberOfRecordsUpdated = 1.  The table has been updated !! but the Session[clientName] seems to be empty. I will investigate why.